# Google App Maker: Add a field with the current date/time

Tags: google-app-maker

new to app maker (and ready to fall in love)

I want every new row to have a field with the date+time that the row was created at. How can I do that?

If you'd like to base your answer on existing code, please base it on the [project-list example](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/project-list/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add a new field to the Data model (e.g. Projects) called, say DateCreated, of type Date.

In the `onCreate` event of the Data Model ('Projects'), add the line:

```
record.DateCreated = new Date();
```

To check your work, add the DateCreated field to the Main page by copying the DueDate field and changing the data binding name to DateCreated.